# Django templates : Looping over Lists contained in Dictionary

Tags: django, django-templates

I currently have a dictionaries : 
In my templatetags I have defined the following function :

```
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

In my template I have the following :

```
{% for a in my_dict|get_item:'key1' %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately, it only does one iteration and then leave the loop. However, the list returned by get_items contains much more than one element (for 'key1').

Any idea what am I missing ?

Thx.

Comment: i think you'll find that the dictionary itself is being passed to 'get_item' not the 'a'.
Also, maybe what you are doing is unnecessary. The templating api allows you to get items from a dictionary like so: {{my_dict.my_key}}